# CCSpriteFrameCache optimization

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]addSpriteFramesWithFile:];
```

That will add sprite frames through a `.plist` file. I would like to ask: if I tried, for whatever reason, to load the same `.plist` file *again*, is `CCSpriteFrameCache` smart enough as to ignore it? Or will it reload it all again, consuming more processing/memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will re-use the already loaded texture, but reload the sprite frames in the plist. It will create new sprite frames and throw out the existing ones.

If you plan to modify a texture atlas and reload it, you'll have to make sure to remove the texture from the texture cache as well, so that it gets reloaded as well.

If you're just lazy and call this method over and over again, it shouldn't be an issue if you do this between scenes but I wouldn't do that during gameplay, since each sprite frame is deallocated and a new one allocated, and a lot of other code runs behind the scenes to load the sprite frames.